# Python script to convert complicated flattened data to JSON

Tags: python, json, csv

Sorry about the vague title, I need some help with Python magic and couldn't think of anything more descriptive.

I have a fixed JSON data structure that I need to convert a CSV file to. The structure is fixed, but deeply nested with lists and such. It's similar to this but more complicated:

```
{
    "foo" : bar,
    "baz" : qux,
    "nub" : [
        {
            "bub": "gob",
            "nab": [
                {
                    "nip": "jus",
                    "the": "tip",
                },
                ...
            ],
        },
        ...
    ],
    "cok": "hed"
}
```

Hopefully you get the idea. Lists on dicts on lists on lists and so forth. My csv for that might look like this:

```
foo, baz, nub.bub, nub.nab.nip, nub.nab.the, cok

bar, qux, "gob" ,,,, "hed"

,,,,, "nab", "jus","tip",,

,,,,, "nab", "other", "values",,
```

Sorry if this is hard to read, but the basic idea is if there's a listed item it will be in the next row, and values are repeated to denote what sub-lists belong to what.

I'm not looking for anyone to come up with a solution to this mess, just maybe some pointers on techniques or things to look into.

Right now I have a rough plan:

I start by turning the header into a list of tuples containing the keys. For each group of rows (item) I'll create a copy of my template dict. I have a function that will set a dict value from a tuple of keys, unless it finds a list. In this case I'm going to call a funky recursive function and pass it my iterator, and continue filling up the dict in that function, and making recursive calls as I find new lists.

I could also do a lot of hardcoding, but what's the fun in that?

So that's my story. Again, just looking for some pointers on what the best way to do this might be. I wrote this quickly so it might be kinda confusing, please let me know if any more info would help. Thanks!

Comment: The formats in question are fundamentally distinct enough that attempting to parse one into the other will prove both problematic, and error prone.  _Why_ do you need a csv file like this?

Comment: Someone's making a test data set for me, and this is the format they used. It's not ideal but I don't want to make them change it (they're doing this by hand...). I can parse it, it's just going to be a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is malformed. Additionally, your json must not contain arrays in order to achieve what you want.

```
def _tocsv(obj, base=''):
    flat_dict = {}
    for k in obj:
        value = obj[k]
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            flat_dict.update(_tocsv(value, base + k + '.'))
        elif isinstance(value, (int, long, str, unicode, float, bool)):
            flat_dict[base + k] = value
        else:
            raise ValueError("Can't serialize value of type "+ type(value).__name__)
    return flat_dict

def tocsv(json_content):
    #assume you imported json
    value = json.loads(json_content)
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        return _tocsv(value)
    else:
        raise ValueError("JSON root object must be a hash")
```

will let you flatten something like:

```
{
    foo: "nestor",
    bar: "kirchner",
    baz: {
        clorch: 1,
        narf: 2,
        peep: {
            ooo: "you suck"
        }
    }
}
```

into something like:

```
{"foo": "nestor", "bar": "kirchner", "baz.clorch": 1, "baz.narf": 2, "baz.peep.ooo": "you suck"}
```

the keys don't preserve any specific order. you can replace `flat_dict = {}` with the construction of an OrderedDict if you want to preserve order.

assuming you have an array of such flat dicts:

```
def tocsv_many(json_str):
    #assume you imported json
    value = json.loads(json_content)
    result = []
    if isinstance(value, list):
        for element in value:
            if isinstance(element, dict):
                result.append(_tocsv(element))
            else:
                raise ValueError("root children must be dicts")
    else:
        raise ValueError("The JSON root must be a list")
flat_dicts = tocsv_many(yourJsonInput)
```

you could:

1. create a `csvlines = []` list which will hold the csv lines for ur file.
2. create a `keysSet = set()` which will hold the possible keys.
3. for each dict you have in this way, add the .keys() to the set. no key order is guaranteed with a normal set; use a sorted set instead. Finally we get the first CSV line.

   ```
    for flat_dict in flat_dicts:
        keysSet.extend(flat_dict.keys())
    csvlines.appens(",".join(keysSet))
   ```
4. for each dict you have (iterate again), you generate an array like this:

   ```
    for flat_dict in flat_dicts:
        csvline = ",".join([json.dumps(flat_dict.get(keyInSet, '')) for keyInSet in keysSet])
        csvlines.append(csvline)
   ```
5. voilah! you have your lines in `csvlines`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I'm going FROM csv. I don't have control over either of the data formats, it's just what I have to use.  I'm probably just going to hard code a lot of stuff to save myself a headache.

Comment: if you come from csv it is even easier. store the first line and break them as keys by commas. for each subsequent lines: break it by commas, zip() it with the keys, iterate, and create a json structure by iteration (and by breaking the keys by dots)